# Getting error in Sqlite ios Failed to open db connection?

Tags: ios, objective-c, sqlite

I'm building an iOS app using storyboards.I have integrated sqlite database in my app.
I'm unable to insert data into the table,i'm getting this error: 
Failed to open db connection

I have created twoo more table with the same code that is working fine but this sports is my third table in which i'm getting this error.

here is my code

```
//SQLlite database code used to get file path
-(NSString *) getSportsFilePath {
    NSString * docsPath= NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains (NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask,  YES)[0];
    return [docsPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"sportsdb.db"];
}

-(int) createTable:(NSString*) filePath {
    sqlite3* db = NULL;
    int rc=0;
    rc = sqlite3_open_v2([filePath cStringUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding], &db, SQLITE_OPEN_READWRITE | SQLITE_OPEN_CREATE, NULL);
    if (SQLITE_OK != rc) {
        sqlite3_close(db);
    }
    else {
        char * query ="CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS sportsselection (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, sportslist  TEXT)";
        char * errMsg;
        rc = sqlite3_exec(db, query,NULL,NULL,&errMsg);
        if (SQLITE_OK != rc) {
            NSLog(@"Failed to create table rc:%d, msg=%s",rc,errMsg);
        }
        sqlite3_close(db);
    }
    return rc;
}

//SQLlite database code is used to insert data into the table
-(int) insert:(NSString *)filePath withName:(NSString *)sportslist {
    sqlite3* db = NULL;
    int rc=0;
    rc = sqlite3_open_v2([filePath cStringUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding], &db, SQLITE_OPEN_READWRITE , NULL);
    if (SQLITE_OK != rc) {
        sqlite3_close(db);
        NSLog(@"Failed to open db connection");
    }
    else {
        NSString * query  = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"INSERT INTO sportsselection (sportslist) VALUES (\"%@\")",sportslist];
        char * errMsg;
        rc = sqlite3_exec(db, [query UTF8String] ,NULL,NULL,&errMsg);
        if (SQLITE_OK != rc) {
            NSLog(@"Failed to insert record  rc:%d, msg=%s",rc,errMsg);
        }
        sqlite3_close(db);
    }
    return rc;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    if ( _sports) {
        for (int j=0;j< _sports.count;j++) {
            int rc= [self insert:[self getSportsFilePath] withName: _sports[j]];
            if (rc != SQLITE_OK) {
                NSLog(@"Failed to insert record");
            }
            else
                NSLog(@"Record is added");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Unrelated, but rather than opening and closing the database each time, it's generally easier/preferable to open it once and leave it open. Also, in your insert code, it's generally preferable to use `?` placeholders in your SQL, and then use sequence of `sqlite3_prepare_v2`, `sqlite3_bind_text`, `sqlite3_step`, and `sqlite3_finalize` (where the "bind" call specifies what value to insert, rather than building the SQL manually).

Comment: maybe you can try this https://github.com/ccgus/fmdb

Answer (score 1):

You should log the return code that `sqlite3_open_v2` returned to determine the cause of the error.

One way you could get the error you describe would be if you failed to call `createTable` before you called `insert`. Usually you would check for the existence of the file, and call `createTable` if it's not found. You don't appear to call `createTable` anywhere.